# Internal EV SSL From A Windows Server 2012 R2 Root CA Shows Up As A Normal Certificate

Tags: active-directory, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, ad-certificate-services

I am trying to setup an internal ev ssl server for all of my internal applications giving ie the little green bar and chrome displaying my company name. It works fine in IE displaying the green bar as well as the company name, however chrome shows it as if it was a normal ssl certificate. Is it possible to add some attribute to it to make chrome trust it or does chrome only trust ev certs from a company such as Digicert.